# Does an NFA necessarily have final states?

Tags: theory, proof, dfa, computation, nfa

I'm trying to prove that all NFAs can be converted into ones with one final state, but I'm not sure how to/if I have to deal with the case of 0 final states.

Comment: The formal definition (on wikipedia, I don't feel like pulling out my book) seems to suggest the set of final states can be empty. So unless you can have a disconnected NFA (i.e. with the final state disconnected), it doesn't seem like you can convert that to a one-final-state-NFA. In any case, I would think you can specify "for all NFAs with > 0 final states", like this question does here: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/14555/29703. On that note, cs.stackexchange is probably a better place for this question.

Comment: Since the empty set is a subset of all other sets, my book also says nothing indicating there needs to be a final state.

Answer (score 1):

Everything depends upon your definitions, but typically:

- The set of accepting states may be empty
- Not all states must be reachable from the initial state

Any NFA without accepting states is trivially equivalent to a DFA with two states: the initial, non-accepting state that loops to itself on all inputs; and an unreachable accepting state that loops to itself on all inputs.